# Laravel 5.3 - Storing and retrieving multiple key-value pairs in session

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm using Laravel 5.3 to build a quiz and I would like to store the results in the session. So, each time the user submits a quiz response, the result is added to the session array.

For example I would like to store the answers something like this:

answers = [q1=correct, q2=correct, q3=incorrect,...]

Then at the end pf the quiz, I want to be able to retrieve and list the results and perhaps style the correct answers green and the wring answers red.

Could anybody provide any guidance on how to achieve this?

Comment: You'll need to send some data back to your controller and let your controller handle creating and passing back the answers as a session. Checkout the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session) on Laravel's sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to store the response as a JSON encoded string.

```
session([
  'answers' => json_encode([
      [
          'q1'=>'correct',
          'q2'=>'correct',
          'q3'=>'incorrect'
      ]
  ])
]);
```

There are more elegant solutions but would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Cliff, I'm going to try this one.

Comment: the json_encode is probably unneeded. The `session()` helper function will accept a response of an array so `session(['answers' => array());` would probably get you a better result.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `session()` helper function for this

#### For Answers

```
public function answer($questionId)
{
  $question = Question::findOrFail($id);

  if(!session()->has('question.answers')) {
    session()->put('question.answers', [[       //Notice the 2 brackets. Y? Checkout below.
      $question->id => request()->get('answer')
    ]]);
  } else {
    session()->push('question.answers', [        //pushing into array
      $question->id => request()->get('answer')
    ]);
  }
}
```

#### At the end of the quiz

```
public function end($question)
{
  $answers = session()->get('question.answers');
  // Output: [ [1 => 'answer1'], [2 => 'answer2'] ]

  $answers = array_flatten($answers);
  // Output: [ 1 => 'answer1', 2 => 'answer2' ]
}
```